# How to create an image map on ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've been looking for a way to create an image map in ASP.NET MVC 3 and so far I didn't found. What I want is quite simple:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/minasmapa.png")" usemap="minasMap"/>
<map name="minasMap">       
    <area shape="circle" href="" coords="249,346,9" />
    <area shape="circle" href="http://" coords="433,392,8" />
</map>
```

The problem is: how to put an action link inside the `href`? What I want is to put something like an action link instead of creating the url myself, because this way I have no problem with servers.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355677/asp-net-mvc-how-to-image-map), but it used Url.RouteUrl, and I couldn't understand how this worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it ... you just have to insert `@Url.Action("PlantInfo","PowerPlant",new {id = "1"})` inside the `href`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the example provided in this article. This allows you to construct an imagemap using c#, both in the view / controller / elsewhere.

http://www.avantprime.com/articles/view-article/9/asp.net-mvc-image-map-helper